# 12.04 won't boot after trying to install 313 nvidia driver

Tags: 12.04, live-cd

I am trying to find a better driver for my graphics card and I tried using the 313 driver for Nvidia in the  X.Org Stable ppa. After the process, i cannot boot into my ubuntu 12.04 partiton. i can boot with a live cd and access the partition and everything is there. How do I go back to the default drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must boot the corrupted Ubuntu system and login to a VT (CTRL+ALT+F2 ... F5) . 
Then remove the PPA you have added. **Before that** you should remove the nvidia driver first.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Now install ppa-purge and remove the ppa

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:<name of ppa here> 
sudo apt-get update
```

I don't know this X.Org Stable ppa you said. If you meant [X-Ubuntu Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) then the above command should be

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Reboot your system.

```
sudo reboot
```

I suggest from now on to use only the Official Ubuntu packages (drivers especially)

Comment: I got everthing working again and now the nvidia x server settings won't start in the dash when it is clicked on.

Comment: How you got everything working again ? Did you follow my answer ? If yes, then you should not have nvidia settings at all.

Comment: Yes everything is working now.